# How does KeePass know when I've used the password?

Tags: macos, copy-paste, keepass

KeePass securely stores any number of passwords, and allows for convenient copy-and-paste operations of stored passwords when a password is needed.

The interesting part: KeePass allows the pasting of a password -- only once. Subsequent attempts to paste the same content are fruitless.

How does KeyPass manage to know when I've used the password?

Comment: This is primary opinion based because it is not documented to how keepass does it. Its likely using an api to see when anything accesses the clipboard. But this is purely speculation.

Comment: @LPChip How can it be opinion based when the source code is available?

Comment: @DavidPostill ah, I was unaware that KeePass is open source. That changes things.

Answer (score 2):

> The interesting part: KeePass allows the pasting of a password -- only
>   once. Subsequent attempts to paste the same content are fruitless.
>
> How does KeyPass manage to know when I've used the password?

Keepass has an auto-clear function. The clipboard can be auto-clear after xx seconds. If the option is activated you will be able to paste several times the same clipboard (password, username, url, etc).

To adjust the timer go on Tools > Security tab : "clipboard auto-clear times (second)":

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to the fact that KeePass is open source, there is nothing easier than checking how it's done yourself. You can download the source code for the version 2.32 [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/keepass/files/KeePass%202.x/2.32/KeePass-2.32-Source.zip/download).

It's written in C# using .NET.

Comment: This answer could even be useful if you pointed out which of the 71k lines of code implemented this feature.

Comment: Sorry, I have a lot of other things to do than to search through as you wrote 71k lines of code for someone else. This is the most of the help I can provide to him. If you want you (or someone else) can try to find it to help him.

Comment: @DanielBeck I agree wholeheartedly, though I shudder to think someone like Dawid Ferenczy shy away from providing information simply because he doesn't have more--especially considering the exciting discoverability it has instilled, vs. eg. the rather hopeless null excitement offered by LPChip--both of which, Mr. Daniel Beck, are unique among the comments so far, _providing_ information relevant this question rather than the mind-numbing drivel littering our playground, accosting us all, until we learn&share&expect more from our peers&selves until we make SE better for all..as a reflex!! =]

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: @DawidFerenczy - If you cannot take the time to provide an actual answer, and explain how this feature works, then I have better things to do then edit your answer so that information is included for you.  Which means your answer is not helpful.